# How to ignore a file in Hadoop if an exception is thrown by the InputFormat RecordReader?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapr

Is it possible in Hadoop to ignore a file and continue reading the others? I am not talking about an exception thrown when a line is corrupted. I am talking about when an exception is thrown by the  InputFormat's RecordReader. I want my job to continue and deal with that file later.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can write an wrapper around `RecordReader` and handle the exception as you want. [Hadoop: Custom RecordReader – Processing](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/).